# Сделайте анимацию маркеров

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Навязчивый и старый вопрос к разрабам, который в 2018 году по-прежнему актуален.

В частности, интересует анимация появления маркера (баунс). Городить свой велосипед через setInterval я не хочу.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: анимации маркеров "из коробки" в API нет; фичреквесты лучше отправлять напрямую в техподдержку сервиса.

Comment: Ну, они сказали что они теперь и здесь.

Comment: Техподдержка API Яндекс.Карт как и раньше находится [на сайте сервиса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/feedback/troubleshooting-docpage/?from=SO#new-feature)

Comment: Конечно находится. И здесь. Здесь - комфортнее. (было - напишу я вскоре)

Comment: Мы вас уже услышали, спасибо за фичреквест! :)
Но вопрос, полагаю, всё же лучше закрыть, поскольку он не может быть решен в рамках stack overflow

Comment: Ну хорошо. Спасибо.